# jQuery - $(this).width() doesn't work if the element is hidden!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I get the width (set in the css styles) of a element that is hidden?

css:

```
a{
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: pink;
}
```

js:

```
var nav = $('.nav');
nav.hide();

nav.hover(function(){
  nav.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
}, function(){
  nav.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
});

$('<a>', {
css: { left: 940 / 2 - ($(this).width() / 2), // <-- here it seems to be 0
click: function(){
    alert($(this).width()); // here it works
    return false;
  }
}).appendTo(nav);
```

Comment: Did you use `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`?

Comment: I posted the code. It's not exactly like this, but its similar to what I have..

Answer (score 3):

This may be impossible, because `$(this)` refers to the `window` object in this case and not the `<a>` element. The `this` reference will be properly bound to the newly created element only if called in the context of a function.

There might be a way to inject the element into `this` using closures but I can't figure out how - interested to see whether somebody can come up with a solution.

Until then, this alternative is less elegant, but will always work:

```
mylink = $('<a>', {
    id: 'test',
   click: function(){
   alert($(this).width()); // here it works
   return false;
 }
}).appendTo($("body")).html("Test");;

mylink.css({ left: mylink.width() / 2});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEQm2/5/)

Answer (score 1):

-Assuming that you want the width of the .nav element (the element that has been hidden).

since you are using `$('<a>')` you are actually creating an anchor tag and in that case $(this) will refer to the anchor element and not the .nav element and so its width is coming out to be 0.

if you wish to get the width of the .nav element u can use

`$('.nav').width();` and this will get you the width of the matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo(nav);
    alert($(this).width());
    $(this).css('left', ($(this).width() / 2));
    return false;
})
```

Comment: @Alexa It it not work please comment me and I'll try to revise it.

Comment: I don't think this can work. The fundamental problem that `this` is not bound to the created element remains

Comment: @Pekka This alerts the width of `a`, also append to `nav` with calculated `left`.

Comment: I promise you this doesn't work, because `this` doesn't point to the right element. Try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/BEQm2/4/

Comment: @abdullah yeah. This is actually pretty tough to do using `this`, if not impossible.